# Generate Authentication Header for Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, key

Why Amazon AWS is so professional and complicated?

I just want my application to upload files to S3. After reading the documents on website, I found I can use "POST" request with just give 2 parameters "key" and "file". (No other stuff, no Policy) But the problem is "key".

"key" is The Authentication Header. But they just put a pseudo code of how to constructing the key which I can't figure out.

```
Authorization = "AWS" + " " + AWSAccessKeyId + ":" + Signature;

Signature = Base64( HMAC-SHA1( UTF-8-Encoding-Of( YourSecretAccessKeyID, StringToSign ) ) );

StringToSign = HTTP-Verb + "\n" +
    Content-MD5 + "\n" +
    Content-Type + "\n" +
    Date + "\n" +
    CanonicalizedAmzHeaders +
    CanonicalizedResource;

CanonicalizedResource = [ "/" + Bucket ] +
    <HTTP-Request-URI, from the protocol name up to the query string> +
    [ sub-resource, if present. For example "?acl", "?location", "?logging", or "?torrent"];

CanonicalizedAmzHeaders = <described below>
```

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html

Can some experienced programmer translate them into PHP or Javascript language? Does it need to include external codes/library? cos I saw some alien functions there.

Comment: Use this, it will do it for you.  http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using php, it's simplest to use the [AWS php SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/). Use [`create_object`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/create_object) to upload a file.

```
// Instantiate the class
$s3 = new AmazonS3();

$response = $s3->create_object('my-bucket', 'myfile.txt', array(
    'fileUpload' => 'upload_me.txt',
));

// Success?
var_dump($response->isOK());
```